# when using -e in bash, exclamation mark before a passing command still doesn't cause the script to fail

Tags: bash

I thought the following script would just print 'hello' and then exit with a '1'

```
#!/bin/bash -e

! echo hello
echo world
```

However, it prints

```
hello
world
```

and exits with a 0

the following script exits with a 1:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

! echo hello
```

and so does the following

```
#!/bin/bash -e

echo hello | grep world
! echo hello
echo world
```

but for some reason the -e option doesn't manage to fail the script when a command returns a failing exit code due to a ! half way through.  Can anybody offer an explanation that will make me feel better about this?

Comment: btw the workaround is `! echo hello || exit 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin

The -e command will fail the script for any command returning a non-zero code, except for some cases, like while loops, or commands returning 0 but inverted with the ! option. Thus your `! echo hello` will return 1 (0 inverted by the `!`) but the `-e` option won't fail.

But if you make a `exit status 42`, you will have your script failed.